# Using awk to add a formula as a new column

Tags: awk

I have a bed file where I want to enter a new column at the end that generates a decimal ratio of the 3rd and 9th column (so the 3rd column divided by the total of the 3rd and 9th column) from the following .bed file:

```
chr1H   4612679 57      42      76      85      142     37      155
chr1H   4612680 60      43      83      89      145     38      160
chr1H   4612681 60      45      83      90      144     38      163
chr1H   4612682 60      45      85      98      148     38      164
chr1H   4612683 60      46      86      99      147     39      164
chr1H   4612684 60      46      86      99      147     39      164
chr1H   4612685 61      46      89      99      149     41      168
chr1H   4612686 62      46      92      100     150     42      168
```

I've read multiple posts but I'm struggling with the formula. I tried `awk -F '\t' '{$(NF+1)= $3 / sum += $3, $9; print}' file.bed`. This is a tab delimted file but I feel like I'm also missing something. I want it to look something like this:

```
chr1H   4612679 57  42  76  85  142 37  155 0.268867925
chr1H   4612680 60  43  83  89  145 38  160 0.272727273
chr1H   4612681 60  45  83  90  144 38  163 0.269058296
chr1H   4612682 60  45  85  98  148 38  164 0.267857143
chr1H   4612683 60  46  86  99  147 39  164 0.267857143
chr1H   4612684 60  46  86  99  147 39  164 0.267857143
chr1H   4612685 61  46  89  99  149 41  168 0.266375546
chr1H   4612686 62  46  92  100 150 42  168 0.269565217
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting the format for number to string conversions `CONVFMT` (default `%.6g`):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="\t"; CONVFMT="%.9f" }
  { $(NF+1)=($3/($3+$9)); print }
' file.bed
```

The same result without assignment to a new field and by changing the number output format `OFMT` (default is also `%.6g`):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="\t"; OFMT="%.9f" }
  { print $0, ($3/($3+$9)) }
' file.bed
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Though I'm getting the error ```fatal: division by zero attempted``` is there a way to make it just input a zero for this?

Comment: In the second example, you could use `{ sum=$3+$9; print $0, sum==0 ? 0 : ($3/sum) }`

Comment: @shaunjc Try without `OFS=FS="\t";`.

Comment: Thanks Freddy, works like a charm!